# how to create an anchor to a file in remote server in html

Tags: html, file, download, anchor, remote-server

I am creating a local web portal in my company intranet. In a page I need to give links to some excel sheets in a remote server.

```
urlFile='file://ed1/cf/a/b/c.xls';
var regRsltLink = $("<a />", {
       href : urlFile,
       text : "heading",
}).appendTo("#legPassRate");
```

The anchor link appears fine. When I click the link, nothing happens. But when I copy the link address and paste in a new tab and launch it, a file download dialog appears and file downloads fine. Is it possible to initiate a file download dialog when i click the anchor link. I get the following link path when i copy the link address.

```
file://ed1/cf/a/b/c.xls
```

Browser : Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Chrome`, `Safari` and `Opera` this **isn't possible** due to their security model. However, there is somewhat of a solution for `Chrome` in that it's possible but it has two requirements:

1. You need to get the user to install [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida)
2. It must be over `https://`

You will probably encounter the same problem for `Firefox` since it usually requires `LocalLink`.

***[Further reading](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html)***

Comment: It does however work fine on `Internet Explorer` so if that's what your intranet users will be using, then no problem