# Download a file from a server using HTML-page (Java, HTML)

Tags: html, file, url, download

I would like to download a file throw the link  from my html-page.

I have this file in a folder on the server. I have shared this folder for all.
The path to my file, for example is:

```
//bogn/folder/spi.jar
```

If I enter the path

```
file://bogn/folder/spi.jar
```

directly to the browser URL - then downloading is going successfully.

As I need to download the file from the HTML-page I use  link:

```
<a href="file://bogn/folder/spi.jar" download> Download JAR </a>
```

The browser asks the question whether to save the file and then ignore saving. I can see the error: Network error.

How I can fix this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why you use `file://` protocol? Use `http://` so you can public access this file.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369147/linking-a-unc-network-drive-on-an-html-page

Comment: http:// doesn't help. At this case browser doesn't find the file at all.

Comment: Trick with 5 slashes (file://///bogn/...) is working for Firefox, for example. But also if put it directly to browser, not from HTML-page.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the file needs to be publicly accessible. If, for example, your html file in in the root web directory, and your jar file is inside "folder" in the same directory, then this will work:

```
<a href="folder/spi.jar" download> Download JAR </a>
```

Comment: Absolutly. However the file located on the server, how I mentioned above.

Comment: Then like Justinas mentioned, you should use the full http(s) path. If you're looking to make a file in a non-public location downloadable then you'll have to use a bit of PHP, or even a REST API for returning files from protected locations.

Comment: I have full control over the server. So I have shared the access to the folder for all users, make it publicly accessible.

Comment: Publicly accessible via http though?

Comment: Detailed situation is this. I have an application with server-side on Java and web-client with Angular. I use Maven to create starting jar-file. 
Now I use our corcorate server and create there a folder for my application. When I start the app on the server then users can connect to it through the browser.
Then my server creates some file, that users should have the possibility to download on their local machines.

Comment: So I have given a public access to the folder where my file is located and the path to it is: //bogn/folder/spi.jar

Answer (score 0):

The similar issue: [how to create an anchor to a file in remote server in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453415/how-to-create-an-anchor-to-a-file-in-remote-server-in-html)

So it seems in Chrome and Firefox it is not allowed to download the files such way from remote server.

**I have found the solution**: I start using Servlets in Java and successfully download the files from remote server to browser.

This link was helpful for me: http://www.journaldev.com/1964/servlet-upload-file-download-example